# Powershell w/split to find multiple pattern matches

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I have a text extract containing multiple instances of filenames (querying googledrive api).  Sample text is shown below.

```
kind           incompleteSearch files                                                                                                                 
----           ---------------- -----                                                                                                                 
drive#fileList         False {@{kind=drive#file; id=1RqYq5t_XEbI52PhkGSURlZRfNbszPmuv; name=TOMCRUISE_2019.TAX; mimeType=text/xml}, @{kind=drive#file; id=1XEQDPCly5_6DVdhmHGfj91dSS_DwLPsL; name=HILARYNOTEWORTHY_2019.TAX; mimeType=text/xml},@{kind=drive#file; id=135CB6BYZTSeKTif8WiUC7Nik2flYKDVE; name=JESNONAME_2019.TAX; mimeType=text/xml}}
```

**Using powershell:**

```
    $pattern=".*=(.*?);.*"  
    (gc $str) -split $pattern
```

This only finds the last pattern match: 
JESNONAME_2019.TAX

How do I find the remaining instances? TOMCRUISE_2019.TAX and HILARYNOTEWORTHY_2019.TAX  I only want the filenames as the final output.

It goes without saying novice here! Thanks for your help

Comment: `name=([^\.]+\.TAX);` https://regex101.com/r/k2BTpu/1

Comment: HI thanks, but your pattern doesn't yield the same result in Powershell. I only want the filenames as the output, nothing else.

Comment: Use `[regex]::matches($str, '(?<=name=)[^;]+') | Foreach {$_.Value}`

Comment: im not very good with regex but you can do something like this `$text.split("Name=").where({ $_ -like "*.*" })` Where `$text` is your `files` column

Comment: Or - if you need `split` badly, try `-split '(?s).*?;\s+name=([^;]+)(?:(?!;\s+name=).)*'`

Comment: Looks like an object, why not do `$Variable.Files.Name` ?
Or `(API Query Code).Files.Name` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks your split example worked.  I wasn't married to split, but I couldn't get your first suggestion to output anything... Since this is a learning experience, I'll keep playing with [regex]::matches to see if I can figure out why its not showing an output.  Thanks for fixing the OP...not sure what you did just added the extract as "code"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I spoke a bit too quickly, the output of the split solution doesn't get rid of the header...can this be done?

Comment: If the header is there you must be reading a file line by line. Use `gc $filepath  -Raw`.

Comment: What if you `| select -expand files`?  Does it look more normal?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for this regex: `([A-Z]+_+[0-9]{4}+.TAX)`, which caputres all instances in the group:

https://regex101.com/r/Xvct56/4